# Splash Screen will not display

Tags: java, android, eclipse, screen, splash-screen

I am trying to implement a Splash Screen using this java and xml code. I created a separate java class from my main activity and placed the java code inside. I created an xml layout in my layout file and placed the xml code inside. However, my app appears normally without a splash screen. It never shows, but the app does not have any errors. Eclipse is not showing any errors either. What could be the cause to this? Thank you in advance. Here is the code.

Java:

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/splashscreen" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:src="@drawable/cat"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello World, splash"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.carouseldemo.main"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/buttonone" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The splash screen display time is 1 sec,can you keep it something around 4-5 Seconds and check it again.

Comment: I increased the time to 10 seconds. It shows a black screen for about a second and opens the app.

Comment: What about Manifest File??Have you registered the splash screen as a Launcher Activity..can you please post your manisfest file here??

Comment: Your java code is Ok and it does n't need to be changed..thier would a minor problem.

Comment: I have updated my question with the Manifest File.

Comment: Replace .MainActivity in manifest with .Splash

Comment: @LuluR be careful next time :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainActivity is launcher activity in manifest file. So, splash is not showing.

Change the launcher activity MainActivity to Splash and write another  for MainActivity.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/buttonone" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>
```

Comment: I was wondering how I could have MainActivity as the android name and Splash at the same time in the activity. Thank you for demonstrating this. Everyone was right, but this is what solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the Handler part with this :

```
Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } finally {
                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                }
            }
        };
    splashThread.start();
```

Comment: The splash screen still does not appear. Thank you for responding, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: what is Menu.class all about ?

Comment: I am using code I found from a similar question I found on here. I tried to make it work before posting the question. I'm just a beginner and it seemed necessary.

Comment: Any service, what do you mean by that? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Check manifest file : <activity
       android:name=".Splash"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>

Comment: I mean did you making any internet connection calls ? BTw check manifest file

Comment: No, I did not make any internet connection calls. I have updated my question with the Manifest file.

Comment: What do I do in the Manifest file?

Comment: by Default your manifest contains Menu.class as first activity to start. So replace `android:name=".Menu"` with `android:name=".Splash"`. Also add one more activity tag for Manu class like `<activity
            android:name=".Manu">
           </activity>`

Comment: My Manifest file is posted above in my question. I do not have android:name=".Menu" Only <activity android:name=".MainActivity" Do I still replace it?

Comment: but in your Spash class, you putting intent from Splash screen to Menu class. ?? Where would you want to navigate right after the Splash screen ?

Comment: I want to navigate to the Main Activity right after the Splash Screen.

Comment: Then in your splash class code, change Menu.class to MainActivity.class. Also perform what i said in manifest file. replace android:name=".MainActivity" with android:name=".Splash". Also add one more activity tag for MainActivity class like <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> </activity>

Comment: Answer suggested by Santhosh is what i am saying about. He is right

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below :

> ```
>  public class Splash extends Activity 
>   {
>    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 1000;  
>        @Override
>          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>                setContentView(R.layout.splash);
>                new Thread(){
>         public void run()
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 sleep(SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
>                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,Menu.class);
>                          Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
>                         Splash.this.finish();
>             }
>             catch (InterruptedException e)
>             {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         };          
>     }.start();
> }
> ```

**EDITED:**

> ```
>   <activity android:name=".Splash" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

Comment: Your code did not bring errors, but the splash page did not come up either.

Comment: I can see that you have set defined `MainActivity` as launcher in your manifest. Besides you should define the `Splash` activity as launcher. Please change it. And check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;
private static final long SPLASHTIME =3000;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            context = getApplicationContext();
            if(savedInstanceState == null){
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
                spHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
            }
        }   


    private Handler spHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
            case STOPSPLASH:
                gotoHomeScreen();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    public void gotoHomeScreen(){

        Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(Splash.this,Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            spHandler = null;

    }
```

try this.

in your manifest

```
<activity android:name="Splash" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve using `CountDownTimer`

```
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    TabSample.class));
            finish();

            MCObject.cancel();



        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

    }
```

Within `OnCreate`

```
     MyCounter MCObject;
    MCObject = new MyCounter(3000, 100);
    MCObject.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your handler

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SPLASH_TIME);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Unless I'm supposed to replace intent with something of my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it might help you.

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

    protected int _splashTime = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(_splashTime);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class));
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}
```

Hope it will help you.