# Splashscreen does not appear, Main activity does

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I coded a Quiz App, now I am prgramming the last steps for my app.I thought a Splash screen would be a nice idea. So i added a Splash Screen activity to my programm and i set it up, now when I wat to start my app the splash screen doesn`t appear. Where is the error?

Main Activity(QuizActivity):

```
     public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private MenuItem menuItem;
private Intent in;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;

private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


    //Randromize the row of the questions
    QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    q.shuffle();
    System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
            q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();
    //End randomizer

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"


    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_stats):
                    Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu2.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);


        updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener1
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();



                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener1

        //Start of Button Listener2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();




                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Oh... wrong your score is 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener2

        //Start of Button Listener3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();




                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Come on, that was not so hard...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);




                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener3

    }


private void updateQuestion() {

    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score",mScore); //pass score to Menu2
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}

    private void updateScore ( int point){
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);

    }


    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Splash Screen (Splash)

```
    public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {


    //Splash screen start

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

}

Splash XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Splash">


      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Menu2 Java:

```
     public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {




private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout2;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);


     TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
     TextView txtHighScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
     ImageView imgTrophyView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trophy1);
     ImageView imgTrophyView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int mScore = intent.getIntExtra ("score",0);
    txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + mScore);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int applyView =sharedpreferences.getInt("currentscore",0);


    SharedPreferences mypref =getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
    if (highScore>= mScore)
        txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);


    else{
        txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + mScore);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore",mScore);
        editor.commit();

    }

    if (applyView >=10 && applyView<20)
        imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (applyView >= 20 && applyView<30){
            imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}}


            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


                mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
                setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

                mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout2, R.string.open, R.string.close);
                mDrawerLayout2.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
                mToggle.syncState();
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
                mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                            case (R.id.nav_home2):
                                Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuizActivity.class);
                                startActivity(accountActivity2);

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }






@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);




}
```

}

Menu2 XML:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Menu2"
      android:id="@+id/drawerLayout2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
            android:background="#f60"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Your score:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="#1abc9c"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Highest score:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Restart Quiz!"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trophy1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu2"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv2"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tint_color_selector2">




</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: please show your Manifest.xml

Comment: I will add it now sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splash Screen will not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722035/splash-screen-will-not-display)

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions carefully - the [android-studio] tag is for questions about the tool itself, not for general programming questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Do this in your Manifest.xml

Comment: Why should OP set the screenOrientation ? And is it OK to keep the intent-filter for MainActivity?

Comment: This will avoid auto rotation in your application. Auto rotation will restart your activity. I am only targeting portrait mode in my application.

Comment: Remove for MainActivity. Keep only for `Splash`

Comment: Thanks worked fine but now the "Hamburger Button" on Menu 2 is disappeared

Comment: Oh  noticed that when I build now the app 2 apps are installing. one works with splah the other only the quiz activity help?

Comment: What is menu 2 now ?

Comment: please remove `<intent-filter>` from your MainActivity in your manifest. Only one Activity should be your launcher Activity. In this case only `Splash` should be your launcher

Comment: Hope now everything is fine.

Comment: All is working fine now the only problem is that in menu2 the "hamburger Button" to open the Navigation drawer disappeared... I update my code then you can probably see the mistake

Comment: in your menu2.xml I dont find any such button called hamburger

Comment: @ProjectX - please leave your question the way it was when you were just asking how to get the Splash screen running. Ask another question if you still need help. And please accept sagar suri's answer because it seems to have been helpful as far as the original question goes.

Comment: I have. Was only a question... I am a little bit depressed now that the hamburger icon does not appear

Comment: I dont find any hamburger button in your Menu2.xml file

Comment: In QuizActivity i dont have too but it works fine i think the problem is that the Override brace finishes too early

Answer (score 2):

move the `intent-filter` from main activity to the splash activity in `manifest.xml` file

```
<activity android:name=".QuizActivity"></activity>

<activity android:name=".Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```